# I want to transform originalArray to finalArray like below

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, transform

folks!

I want to transform originalArray to finalArray like below.

Anyone help, Thanks, in advance.

As you can see, I want to sort by "cnt_bought", like "Sam","Alice"

```
var originalArray = [
    {"name":"Sam","cnt_bought":0},
    {"name":"John","cnt_bought":5},
    {"name":"Alice","cnt_bought":0},
    {"name":"Bob","cnt_bought":31}
];

var finalArray = [
    {"cnt_bought":0, "name" : ["Sam","Alice"]},
    {"cnt_bought":5, "name" : ["John"]},
    {"cnt_bought":31, "name" : ["Bob"]}
];
```

Comment: Can you post your attempts so far? One of the basic requirements of SO is to have already tried a solution, even if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function mapAndSortArray(originalArray) {
    var finalArray = [];
    while (originalArray.length > 0) {
        var found = false;
        var next = originalArray.shift();
        for (var i = 0; i < finalArray.length; i++) {
            if (next.cnt_bought === finalArray[i].cnt_bought) {
                finalArray[i].name.push(next.name);
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (! found) {
            next.name = [next.name];
            finalArray.push(next);
        }
    }

    finalArray.sort(function(a, b) {
        var tbr = 0;
        if (a.cnt_bought < b.cnt_bought) {
            tbr = -1;
        }
        else if (a.cnt_bought > b.cnt_bought) {
            tbr = 1;
        }
        return tbr;
    });

    return finalArray;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your post. However, your script don't work. can't find newObj, and finalArray is [{},{},{},{}]

Comment: No prob. can you vote up my post and accept it as the answer then?

Comment: Yeah...I did vote up your answer and accept is as the answer. Thank you again~!